# State does not update using UseEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `notes` state array that I have that stores the user's inputs. When a user initially opens this specific screen, the component should fetch the user's notes, and return that array or an empty one depending on if they have data or not, and display the notes on the screen if they exist. When they add a note, the component should push this new note to the `notes` array and call `AsyncStorage.setItem` to store the new array. The component should then re-render with the state variable changing.

When I run this code, though, nothing happens. My state does not seem to update, and even though I submit text, the screen does not re-render, nor does any new text appear in the section it is supposed to appear in. Anyone know where I went wrong?

**UPDATE:** I have added the full code block [here](https://pastebin.com/kqcvyUh9)

```js
const [notes, setNotes] = React.useState(null);

let getNotes = async () => {
  try {
    let json = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`${id}-notes`);
    if (json != null) {
      setNotes(JSON.parse(json));
    } else {
      setNotes([]);
     }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(notes, '- Has changed');
  getNotes();
}, [notes]);

// user input check
<TextInput 
  style={styles.text} 
  value={note} 
  onChangeText={text => {setNote(text)}}
  onSubmitEditing={event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.text) {
      setNotes([...notes, event.nativeEvent.text]);
      AsyncStorage.setItem(`${id}-notes`, JSON.stringify(notes), (e) => {});
      setVisible(false);
     }
  }}
  multiline={true} 
  returnKeyType='go'
/>

// what i want the screen to render
{notes && notes.map(note => {
  <Note note={note} />
})}
```

Comment: Is the console.log "Has Changed" printing in the console?

Comment: Yes, but it prints like, tens of times repeatedly instead of just once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is that the state is not being set,
I think the problem is that you aren't returning anything from you `map` function.

Either add the `return` keyword.
**Like this:**

```
{notes && notes.map(note => {
  return <Note note={note} />
})}
```

Or simply remove the curly-brackets to turn the statement into an "implicit return".
**Like this:**

```
{notes && notes.map(note => (
  <Note note={note} />
))}
```

Comment: Did not work. Still nothing show up where it should.

Comment: Yeah, now I notice that you don't even return anything from the component.. In React, components generally return markup. In other words, wrap the template in the component in a `return` as well.

Comment: Ah I apologize, it all is wrapped in a return. I just did not want to post the full code because it's too long. I could send you a pastebin of the full code if you want to look at that.

Comment: I see. In one of the comments you've mentioned that the `console.log` prints multiple times. This is because you have `notes` in the dependency array, which makes it so that every time the state updates, the `useEffect` runs again and updates the state again. Have you tried removing it and providing an empty array instead?